# jquery get a custom (made up) Attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a the following html piece :

```
<div onClick="javascript:getComments(this);" store-id="143568" class="CountryRow" style="padding: 4px;"><div class="flag flag_az"></div> &nbsp; Azerbaijan</div>
```

and I would like to create a jquery function to get the value of `store-id`. I have the following however its not working :

```
 getComments = function(input) {
   fValue = $(input).val( $(input).attr("store-id") );
   alert('the ID :'+fValue);
 }
```

can someone be kind enough to tell me what it is that I am doing wrong.

Comment: For what it's worth, HTML5 provides a standard facility for custom attributes like that. http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works perfectly:

```
getComments = function(input) {
  fValue =  $(input).attr("store-id");
  alert('the ID :'+fValue);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mHBuE/

Comment: thanks alot.. I will accept your answer in 5 mins (after stackoverflow allows me to). @LeviMorrison thanks anyways ;)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at jQuery [custom selectors](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/547-jQuery-Custom-Selectors-Holy-Cow-That-Is-So-Badass-.htm).  Personally, I would use HTML5 [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) for cases such as this which is already [supported](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) in jQuery.

For whatever it's worth, considering the parameter I believe what are you trying to originally perform should be done like

```
getComments = function(input) {
   fValue =     $(input).html( $(input).attr("store-id") );
   alert('the ID :'+fValue.html());

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

all you have to do is :

```
fValue = $(input).attr("store-id");
```

your snippet is trying to add to the 'value' attribute of a div (which does not exist)