# how to copy title attribute of a <span> to text area using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, title

I am adding smilies to my comments

for which i using following code

```
      <span class="smilies" id="angry" title="X-("></span>
```

where

```
.smilies{
background: url("../images/smilies-sprite.png");
display: inline-block;
height: 22px;
margin-bottom: -7px;
width: 24px;
}

#angry{
  background-position: -70px -10px;
}
```

I want that when somebody click on **id=angry** the title attribute of id=angry shell be copied to my comments textarea

```
    <textarea id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
```

Comment: `$('.smilies').click(function(){$('#comments')[0].value += this.title;});`, basically. Do you want to overwrite the textarea's contents, or add it at the caret's position?

Comment: And what exactly do you have problems with? [How to bind a click event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+how+to+bind+click+event+handler&submit=search), [how to read an attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087093/jquery-get-a-custom-made-up-attribute-value) or [how to set the content of a textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415602/set-value-of-textarea-in-jquery)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it and work for any smilies

```
$('span.smilies').on('click', function() {
    var comments = $('#comments');
    comments.val(comments.val() + $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/JVDES/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#angry").click(function(){
 $("#comments").val($(this).attr("title"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

to add it to the end of the current textarea line you could do something like

```
$('#angry').click(function(){

    var smiley = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#comments').val($('#comments').val()+smiley);

});
```

However the better one would be to look up the caret insert stuff. that way you can insert at the caret (blinking line). Google it, there should be a lot of info about it. BBCode editors is what you will probably want to look at.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to mention the carat issue. This is the REAL problem the OP will come up against. I'm not familiar with BBCode, but Rangy is another option.

Comment: BBCode is the term often used to describe a text input where you can use tags like [b] [/b] for bolding text. they often include smiley code too. Used frequently on forums to provide limited but safer text decorating, layout and linking

Answer (score 0):

This is an example. On click event will set the value of the title

```
$('#angry').click(function() {
  $('#comments').val($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Comment: you are very quick, but commentsis not a class here :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#angry').click(function() {
  $('#comments').val($('#comments').val() + $('#angry').attr('title'));
});
```