# How to get the value of a custom attribute using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Can you help me with my problem?
My problem is, I am trying to create a dynamic form. In my form I have a part that has a check all function. But what I want is. The check all function will trigger if the custom attribute is found.

Here's my sample code:

```
 <input type="checkbox" data-check="checkAll" />CHECK ALL<br/> <!-- The data-check is used for validating if the user check the checkbox -->

<div id="container">
    <div id="parent1">
        <div id="child1">
            <input type="checkbox" val="45" />ITEM A
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parent2">
        <div id="child2">
            <input type="checkbox" val="41" />ITEM B
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="parent3">
        <div id="child3">
            <input type="checkbox" val="1" />ITEM C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The expected result should be:

1. After the user check the check all checkbox, the system should validate if there is an existing data-check value.
2. If found, the checkboxes from the parents  should be checked

By the way I am using jquery 1.5.2

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087093/jquery-get-a-custom-made-up-attribute-value

Comment: Side note: please consider `data-val` as name for your custom attribute as recommended for HTML5. Usage - `$("#parent3 input").data("val")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$("input[data-check='checkAll']").change(function(){
     $("#container :checkbox").prop("checked",this.checked);
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rBGYa/)

Comment: i got an error
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'prop'

Comment: @RochelleCanale: What is the version of jQuery file are you using? Is it less then 1.6??

Comment: I am using jquery 1.5.2

Comment: @RochelleCanale: Ok, that is why you are getting the above error. You need to upgrade to jQuery version 1.6 or above, if possible. As **.prop()** method was added in jQuery version 1.6 release.

Comment: Ok thanks, but sad to say that I can't upgrade my version. Because I am restricted for accessing the file upgrades. But anyway thanks. You really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To read the `data-*` attribute value you can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), like in `$(el).data('check')`

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);// this is the checkbox
    var checkdata = $this.data('check');
    if(checkdata == 'all'){
    }
})
```

or you you want to add a handler for only the check all checkbox then

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][data-check="checkAll"]').change(function(){
    //this will be fired only of the checkall checkbox is changed
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D3CPu/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var customData = $('input[type="checkbox"]').data("check");
```

Try the above

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[data-check='checkAll']").change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
$("#container").find(":checkbox").prop("checked",true);
}
else{
$("#container").find(":checkbox").prop("checked",false);
}

});
```

reference **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** and **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**